# How to organize information about dishes in a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, data-representation

I'm going to create a SQL database to store the information about cookery. There going to be dishes, ingredients, etc.

The problem is how to represent the information about a dish in order to include all of the ingredients related to the dish.

For example, there is a table with ingredients containing fields such as:
**- id

- ing_name

- ing_type

...

etc**

And another table contains the information about a dish such as:
**- id

- dish_name

- dish_type

...

- etc**

And there must be all of the ingredients related to the diss, however the amount of them can be different, so that I have no idea how to store ingredients related to the dish in the table.

Lets say that the dish with id = 1 contains ingredients with id = 3, 5, 8 and 12, how can I represent this information in the table about dishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just discovered a Many-To-Many relationship!

You will want 3 tables to handle this data, "Dish", "Ingredient", and "DishIngredient".  "DishIngredient" is sometimes called a "Junction table".  It stores information about the relationship between the other 2 tables.

Your table structure will look something like this:

- Dish

  - DishID
  - Name
- Ingredient

  - IngredientID
  - Name
- DishIngredient

  - DishID
  - IngredientID
  - Quantity

You will want `Dish.DishID`, and `Ingredient.IngredientID` to be primary keys, with foreign keys in `DishIngredient`.
The primary key on `DishIngredient` should be a composite key on *both* DishIngredient.DishID and `DishIngredient.IngredientID`.

Making the primary key on `DishIngredient` a composite key isn't absolutely required, It could have its own ID, but the composite primary key will prevent the same ingredient from being in the same dish multiple times.

You can connect these tables with a join to get all the ingredients for a recipe, like this:

```
SELECT 
    Dish.Name AS Dish, 
    Ingredient.Name AS Ingredient, 
    DishIngredient.Quantity AS Quantity
FROM Dish
INNER JOIN DishIngredient 
    ON Dish.DishID = DishIngredient.DishID
INNER JOIN Ingredient 
    ON DishIngredient.IngredientID = Ingredient.IngredientID
WHERE Dish.Name ='Pizza'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been very helpful!